# Syntax highlighting for >= and <= operators in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I am trying to get proper syntax highlighting for the Matlab operators `>=` and `<=`. Currently, only `<` and `>` are highlighted -- not the `=`. But e.g. `==` is highlighted.

I've looked in the `Matlab.tmLanguage` file, and both `&gt;=`and `&lt;=` are included in the operator regex.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Re. self-answering. Formulating this question, I found the answer (to be posted in a sec.), but I'm posting Q and A, since it seems to be explicitly encouraged by SO.

Comment: It is encouraged. Also you can just fill in the question and answer at the same time by checking a box when asking a question. It might also be worth posting something to the Sublime Text [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) and/or [feature requests](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/) if you haven't already. Unfortunately (for now) development seems to have stopped again on Sublime Text.

Comment: @andyb, do you know if there exists an (semi-) official git repo of the standard packages? I googled, but couldn't find it. After the advent of SO and Github, forums and feature request lists, just seems so very inefficient.

Comment: @AdamAL unfortunately, only Jon Skinner (Sublime's author) maintains the "official" packages. However, many people have published improvements to `.tmLanguage` files, along with plugins, color schemes, etc. The best place to look is [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they have any Matlab improvements, but if you're willing to maintain one, I'm sure many people would appreciate it.

Comment: Raising a feature request could result in your suggested change making it back into the default package (if Jon is reading the requests still!). I don't know of any other resources on top of what has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the complete regex, which is found under:

```
</dict>
<key>operators</key>
<dict>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>Operator symbols</string>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\s*(==|~=|&gt;|&gt;=|&lt;|&lt;=|&amp;|&amp;&amp;|:|\||\|\||\+|-|\*|\.\*|/|\./|\\|\.\\|\^|\.\^)\s*</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.operator.symbols.matlab</string>
</dict>
```

The issue is the order of the `or`'ed sub-expressions (`|&gt;|&gt;=|&lt;|&lt;=`). E.g. `&gt;` is matched before `&gt;=`, which then isn't matched at all. 
So the solution is to change the order of the subexpressions, matching the longer first. I.e. change the `match` string to:

```
 \s*(==|~=|&gt;=|&gt;|&lt;=|&lt;|&amp;|&amp;&amp;|:|\||\|\||\+|-|\*|\.\*|/|\./|\\|\.\\|\^|\.\^)\s*
```