# How can I add syntax highlighting for operators in sublime text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I want to highlight `+-*=/[](){}%^&$` characters with a color of my choice.

I tried to do it with some answers I found on stackoverflow, but without success [Syntax highlighting for >= and <= operators in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167025/syntax-highlighting-for-and-operators-in-sublime-text) When I tried it, it changed the color of all normal text.

I noticed it's possible to customize syntax highlighting, but the article on it is pretty long. http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html

Any clue how to do it ? I already have an existing theme I made, all I want is to highlight those characters.

Comment: A clue: if you need help, post the code you have trouble with. Describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: You can't just decide to highlight something in your `.tmTheme` file, it has to have a scope assigned to it by the `.tmLanguage`/`.sublime-syntax` language definition. What language are you working with? Have you checked the scopes of the operators to see if they're unique? The very first line at the top of your second link clearly states that guide is deprecated. Did you bother finding and/or reading the up-to-date version? Yes, it's long, but that's because this is a very complicated subject. You would do well to do a significant amount of background research first.

Comment: MattDMo : Working with C++. You're right, I was just reading that syntax thingm doesn't seem simple. Don't you think anybody has done it yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it, apparently some characters like [] and ; aren't "scoped", but for the other, I did it. Here is what I added in my .tmtheme

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>char ops</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>keyword.operator.arithmetic, punctuation.definition.generic.end, punctuation.definition.parameters, keyword.operator.assignment, punctuation.separator, keyword.operator.comparison, punctuation.definition.scope,punctuation.definition.block, punctuation.definition.dictionary, punctuation.definition.list,punctuation.definition.arguments </string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#ffff50</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```